# Probability of 5 slots with 4 possibilities having an outcome with 2 matches and 3 matches.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have 5 slots. They can each be marked by a red, blue, green, or yellow marker. What is the probability that I have an outcome of the highest number of matching colors being 2? 3?

Things I know:

The probability of each slot having a single color is an independent event of $\frac{1}{4}$.

[red] [red] [green] [green] [green] has a highest outcome of 3.

[red] [red] [yellow] [yellow] [green] has the highest outcome of 2.

The total possible outcomes is $4^5$

This problem is driving me nuts. I have been trying google, but I don't think I'm searching for the correct terms to solving this problem. I can hand solve it out, but I really need a mathematical formula.

EDIT: Order matters.
[red] [red] [green] [green] [green] and [red] [green] [red] [green] [green] are different outcomes while both have highest outcome of 3.

EDIT2: I hand solved the problem with 4 slots and got:

```
 Highest Outcome Count | Probability
                     1 | 0.09375
                     2 | 0.703125
                     3 | 0.1875
                     4 | 0.015625
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution):

$$P\left(R=r\wedge B=b\wedge G=g\wedge Y=y\right)=\frac{5!}{r!b!g!y!}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{5}$$
This for $r,b,g,y\in\left\{0,1,2,3,4,5\right\} $ with $r+b+g+y=5$.

If $N$ denotes the highest number of matching colors, then by symmetry:

$P\left(N=3\right)=12P\left(R=3\wedge B=2\wedge G=0\wedge Y=0\right)+12P\left(R=3\wedge B=1\wedge G=1\wedge Y=0\right)$

and:

$P\left(N=2\right)=12P\left(R=2\wedge B=2\wedge G=1\wedge Y=0\right)+4P\left(R=2\wedge B=1\wedge G=1\wedge Y=1\right)$

Comment: Thanks for replying! For my problem, the order of outcome matters. I don't think this accounts for different orders of outcomes.

Comment: Finally got it, I needed this and multiply it with all possible permutations of the smaller sets to get the right probability. So I need to do $[\frac{5!}{3!1!1!0!}*(\frac14)^5]*(\frac{_5P_3}{2}) + [\frac{5!}{3!2!0!0!}*(\frac14)^5]*(\frac{_5P_2}{2})$

Comment: What do you mean with factor $\frac{5P3}{2}$? Has it value $12$? By arrangement $(3,1,1,0)$ two colors are selected to be used exactly $1$ time. This can be done on $\binom42=6$ ways. Next, one of the remaining $2$ colors is selected to be used exactly $3$ times. This can be done on $2$ ways. The (utmost) remaining color is not used. In total there are $6\times2=12$ possibilities. For arrangement $(3,2,0,0)$ there will also be $12$ possibilities. (First choose $2$ colors that are not used, then choose a color that is used $3$ times. The remaining color is used $2$ times).